# How to identify a user from SAML Response?

Tags: java, saml-2.0, spring-saml, shibboleth

I have implemented  Single Sign On  to access my Sp application .It uses a shibboleth server as Identity Provider .After i login in idp system  I receive a Saml response from Idp 
which contains Saml Assertion but i don't now how to identify this user in my app. 
The saml assertion contains this data:

*

> The following attributes were provided by your identity provider
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
>   AAdzZWNyZXQxlKzPy2zEKyk/rEaN2jVTXi6mEvaFbOzXwkMNEZMB+TkQcmWW4LZT70hx3cAVEyrBSdXkT2glVkPGuncVMe5PfFipJjVAGE7jdRGsFef6CqzDArE9Olw/1EhkIA/S3hu9IpiU
>   urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.9 affiliate@test.ukfederation.org.uk,
>   affiliate, i8mqNNzYfweNDzGr/PafYaMzWko=,
>   alice@test.ukfederation.org.uk urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.1
>   affiliate@test.ukfederation.org.uk, affiliate,
>   i8mqNNzYfweNDzGr/PafYaMzWko=, alice@test.ukfederation.org.uk
>   urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.10 affiliate@test.ukfederation.org.uk,
>   affiliate, i8mqNNzYfweNDzGr/PafYaMzWko=,
>   alice@test.ukfederation.org.uk urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6
>   affiliate@test.ukfederation.org.uk, affiliate,
>   i8mqNNzYfweNDzGr/PafYaMzWko=, alice@test.ukfederation.org.uk

*

I was trying to use name-id to identify users in my system with users in idp ,but this values changes after each login.

For example : Google Suite  uses urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress as name identifier 
and it possible to find the user using email address ,but in this case i am stuck. 
Please which is the best way to do this ? Should i use attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the Object identifier (OID) format.

e.g. 1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6 is eduPersonPrincipalName

Refer [this](https://www.internet2.edu/products-services/trust-identity/mace-registries/internet2-object-identifier-oid-registrations/).

Comment: Thank you @nzpcmad that is helpful  ,but i tried with another organisation in the same server.(different sso -endpoint) and i got this response :
urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6 member@xxxx.co.uk, cn=sstreet,ou=users,o =49ff400e-14f7-4902-8089-1f9b93e0152b, dc=tenant1 ,dc=com ,hDhFcskKp/UiYoxqwAKokCv8sJs=, ssterert, 5a11d0e-e8a7-a9b2-8ea9-a2ea9de0a42e@xxxxx.co.uk  is seems as ldap query.
what is eduPersonPrinciaplname in this case?

Comment: At a guess, either cn=sstreet i.e. sstreet or member@xxxx.co.uk.